# IDA interpretation of switch-case statement

Tags: ida, c++

This is my first question on this forum, so I hope that it would not be offensive or redundant.

So recently I am attempting to developing some kernel extensions for Apple's macOS using the IOKit framework. However, in the debugging process, I encountered some confusions while looking at the assembly and pseudocode of my binaries generated by IDA.

Currently, the greatest issue is how the normal switch case statement is interrupted by the decompiler — `_bittest64` commands would be yielded with huge numbers as arguments. I am somewhat sure that it has to do with the “lower-bound” of the cases, but I don't know how exactly should I comprehend it. Here is an example:

[image: Actual code]
[image: Hex-Rays decompiler pseudocde]

I can't really see how they relate, particularly the `_bittest64` part. Just by the way, the enum `kBluetoothIntelHardwareVariantJfP = 0x11` and `kBluetoothIntelHardwareVariantSlrF = 0x19`.

Happy thanksgiving!

Comment: Welcome to Reverse Engineering StackExchange! Please copy / paste your code *as a text* instead of pictures. It will help others to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a compiler optimization used to implement `switch` statements that have many cases leading to one location. Note that the weird output is not Hex-Rays' doing, but rather, a more-or-less direct translation of what's in the assembly language. You didn't show the assembly for your snippet, but here's similar disassembly from a database I have open:

```
.text:0000000061FEA1C8     lea     eax, [rdi-33h]
.text:0000000061FEA1CB     cmp     eax, 0Eh
.text:0000000061FEA1CE     ja      short loc_61FEA1F8
.text:0000000061FEA1CE
.text:0000000061FEA1D0     mov     edx, 6381h
.text:0000000061FEA1D5     bt      edx, eax ; <- this becomes _bittest
.text:0000000061FEA1D8     jnb     short loc_61FEA1F8
```

And here's its Hex-Rays decompilation:

```
  if ( (vChildOp - 51) > 0xE )
    return /* ... */;

  v6 = 25473;
  if ( !_bittest(&v6, vChildOp - 51) )
    return /* ... */;
```

Let's take a closer look at your snippet. You said that `kBluetoothIntelHardwareVariantJfP = 0x11` and `kBluetoothIntelHardwareVariantSlrF = 0x19`. Now look at the constant, `0x39E0000LL`. This is `11100111100000000000000000b` in binary:

```
11 1001 1110 0000 0000 0000 0000
|| |  | |||- bits 0-16 clear   
|| |  | ||-- bit 17 (i.e., 0x11): first bit set
|| |  | |--- bit 0x12 set
|| |  | ---- bit 0x13 set
|| |  ------ bit 0x14 set
|| --------- bit 0x17 set
|----------- bit 0x18 set
------------ bit 0x19: last bit set
```

Notice that the `switch` statement in your example has 7 cases leading to the same label, and that two of the cases correspond to bits `0x19` and `0x11`? It is not a coincidence that the constant in the snippet has 7 bits set, including bits `0x11` and `0x19`! The `bt` instruction, translated as the `_bittest` intrinsic, is just checking to see whether `hardwareVariant`, or `a2` in the decompilation, is one of the values `0x11`-`0x14` or `0x17-0x19`. It performs all 7 comparisons at the same time.

The `if`-statement on the outside is the `default` check: it ensures that the value of `a2` is at most `0x19` -- if it's not, it jumps to the `default` location, i.e., does nothing.

Comment: OT on a simple glance  result is an unassigned local a garbage only assigned a value inside the if block{} so does this function return garbage?

Comment: @blabb Note that, in the source code, the function's true return type is `void`. Hex-Rays erroneously thinks this function returns a value, so it tries to create an assignment expression for the `rax` register. In this case, the only such assignment takes place as part of the `bt` sequence, which is why we get garbage inside of an `if`-statement.

Comment: Thanks and again OT  so the Function Type also needs to be modified manually as void blah(x,y) instead of __int64  to fix this but if there was no source to rely how to grapple with this apparently erroneous return in general

Comment: @blabb I rely on clues like the one you identified. If some paths through a function don't return a value,  it probably returns `void`. If none of the calling functions use the return value, it may or may not be `void`, but there's no harm in marking it as such. If a function supposedly returns `void`, but calling functions show usage of uninitialized values allocated in the `rax` register after the call, it does not return `void`. There's a recursive effect; if you determine a called function returns `void`, that may give you evidence that a calling function does also.

Comment: ok thanks again actually i was looking for some magic recipes :) to peer at decompiled output  without  accompanying disassembly or source